# Android: why is broadcast receiver not called before fragment is created on boot up?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

forgive me for my misunderstanding but I'm trying to determine when my android device is booted up from a power-off. I am able to successfully receive a broadcast when the device boots up, however, it is done way after the activity and fragment are created.

First off, here's my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application

       ....

        <receiver android:name=".ui.BootCompleteReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        ....

</application>
```

BootCompleteReceiver.java:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Toast.makeText(context, "BOOTCOMPLETERECEIVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Singleton.getInstance().isRebooted = true;

        Toast.makeText(context, "BOOTCOMPLETERECEIVER isRebooted = "
                + Singleton.getInstance().isRebooted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MainActivity onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MainActivity isRebooted = "
                + Singleton.getInstance().isRebooted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends VerticalGridFragment
{

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "MAINFRAGMENT onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    ...
}
```

Singleton.java:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton ourInstance = new Singleton();

    public static boolean isRebooted = false;

    // Private constructor to contain only one instance of a Singleton
    private Singleton()
    {

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        // If no instance of a Singleton exist, create one
        if (ourInstance == null)
        {
            ourInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }
}
```

Putting some toast messages in, I see that the MainActivity Toast message is called first, which creates MainFragment. Afterwards once the fragment is created is when I receive the Toast message from BroadcastReceiver.

Is it possible to have the BroadcastReceiver be called first before the MainFragment is created up?

Comment: Show also your `Singleton.java`.